# Can godoc tool hide constants and variables content?

Tags: go, godoc

I want to write some document for my program and use godoc to generate a html document page.

However, it reveals some exported constants and variables. They are exportable because other packages in this program need them. But it is unnecessary for a user to acknowledge these constants and variables. And showing them in document is ugly.

So can I hide constants and variables part in godoc page for my personal packages?

Comment: You can't. If they are exported, anyone can access them. Consider using `internal` packages if they're not meant for the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

> So can I hide constants and variables part in godoc page for my personal packages?

No.